# Matplotlib encounters this warning "'c' argument looks like a single numeric RGB or RGBA sequence"

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to reproduce the example in this [post](https://duncanmakerclass.wordpress.com/2017/03/02/sklearns-perceptron/)

which produces this figure.

[image]

this part

```
def plot_decision_regions(X, y, classifier, test_idx=None, resolution=0.02):
    markers = ('s', 'x', 'o', '^', 'v')
    colors = ('red', 'blue', 'lightgreen', 'gray', 'cyan')
    cmap = ListedColormap(colors[:len(np.unique(y))])

    x1_min, x1_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
    x2_min, x2_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1
    xx1, xx2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x1_min, x1_max, resolution), np.arange(x2_min, x2_max, resolution))
    Z = classifier.predict(np.array([xx1.ravel(), xx2.ravel()]).T)
    Z = Z.reshape(xx1.shape)
    plt.contourf(xx1, xx2, Z, alpha=0.4, cmap=cmap)
    plt.xlim(xx1.min(), xx1.max())
    plt.ylim(xx2.min(), xx2.max())

    X_test, y_test = X[test_idx, :], y[test_idx]
    for idx, cl in enumerate(np.unique(y)):
        plt.scatter(x=X[y == cl, 0], y=X[y == cl, 1], alpha=0.8, c=cmap(idx), marker=markers[idx], label=cl)

    if test_idx:
        X_test, y_test = X[test_idx, :], y[test_idx]
        plt.scatter(X_test[:, 0], X_test[:, 1], c='black', alpha=1.0, linewidth=1, marker='+', s=55, label='test set')
```

causes this warning

> 'c' argument looks like a single numeric RGB or RGBA sequence, which
>   should be avoided as value-mapping will have precedence in case its
>   length matches with 'x' & 'y'.  Please use a 2-D array with a single
>   row if you really want to specify the same RGB or RGBA value for all
>   points.

I guess something wrong with matplotlib, since the [doc](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html) discusses this.

## question

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should change the line as:

```
X_test, y_test = X[test_idx, :], y[test_idx]
for idx, cl in enumerate(np.unique(y)):
    plt.scatter(x=X[y == cl, 0], y=X[y == cl, 1], alpha=0.8, color=cmap(idx), marker=markers[idx], label=cl)
```

Comment: color=c... is the issue, need to use color=